# Is it possible to change Msysobjects in ms access

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

Is it possible to change MSYSObjects table values manually.

Especially the Database field in MSysObjects Table

Because i need to change path of linked table manually. Linked table manager is no use in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `connect` property of `tabledefs` through VBA. Tampering with the system tables is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to prefer the following  route:
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/details.htm

Regards